# Telnet - reading the last line as input, per frame

Tags: python, telnet

I plan to make a "telnet bot". 
There is a game which has a telnet server built ingame, that you can turn on. Now, this telnet server logs all of the activity in the console (kills, players joining, chat, etc) and you can also type stuff into putty and it will be received ingame.

Anyway, I tried to use Python Telnetlib, but there doesn't seem to be any function that reads the last line. I also tried using sockets, but I don't quite understand the Telnet protocol.

Is there a way to use telnetlib or sockets to do the following thing?:

```
#def readAndDo():
serverOutput = telnet.readLastLine() #doesn't exist, this would be like the thing I need
if "> AuthorizeMe" in serverOutput.splitlines()[:-1]:
    nickname = serverOutput[2:-13]
    tn.write(b"playerReq = playergetByName(\"" + nickname + "\")\n") 
    tn.write(b"playerReq = playerInfo(\"playerReq\")\n")
    username = telnet.readLastLine()
    print username
    readAndDo()
if "Victim" in serverOutput:
    print serverOutput
    readAndDo()
else:
    sleep(1)
    print serverOutput
    readAndDo()
readAndDo()
```

Comment: in python there are four ways to write strings, so no need to escape `"`.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "the last line"? Do you mean the final line, or do you mean the most recently previous line?

Comment: The latest line, so the last line the server sent

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to read the last line in telnet, but want to react on situations, where the telnet server wants input. There is no other way to parse the whole messages, the server sends and answer when the server expects answers.

Comment: That's not true, the game sends all console data from stuff that happens ingame. And yes, I want to read the last line, but thanks for telling me it's impossible, that's at least good to know.